# The group corresponding to the Rubik's cube

Tags: group-theory

Why is this group never studied in a group theory course at university?  Is it too complicated or is it just not useful in connecting ides to other systems like vector spaces, creating modules, etc?

I would like to study this group but I did not find much useful info.  Can you please point me to something easy to understand for a student who only took abstract algebra 1 and linear algebra 1?

Comment: I feel certain that it is presented as an object of study, but it's not called out for special mention.  Is there something unusual about it that would merit such mention (other than its notoriety)?

Comment: Is it similar to a familiar group?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm afraid I'm not intimately familiar with the group, other than the relatively obvious properties of it.  There's a Wikipedia article on it, though, surely.

Comment: Did you even read the wikipedia article? Its cardinality is about $43\times10^{18}$ ... how do you even study this thing?

Comment: I think it's quite large and unwieldy for study in a course. Its presentation by generators and relations is fairly opaque, making it difficult to work with. I'm sure the group theory played a large part in determining that every cube can be solved in $\leq 20$ moves, but checking this still required some absurd amount of computer time (about 35 computer-years, if [this is to be believed](http://www.cube20.org/))

Comment: I have always found this to be a sort of silly example of a group to single out, and I don't see why it would be a good example to say introduce representations.

Comment: @Joppy that was my suspicion.  All of the groups we covered were super easy to understand in the course, like the dihedrals, cyclic and symmetric groups for example.

Comment: @Kartik, wikipedia articles are usually too broad or contain errors and falsehoods.

Answer (score 5):

The Rubik's cube group *is* studied in some universities:

[W.D.Joyner's Lecture notes on the mathematics of the Rubik's cube](http://akbar.marlboro.edu/~mahoney/groups/wdj_rubik_lecture/rubik_nts.htm)

[The Mathematics of the Rubik's cube](http://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/rubik.pdf)

[Group Theory and the Rubik’s Cube](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik's%20Cube.pdf)

[Mathematics of the Rubik's Cube](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/match/rubik.html)

[Rubik’s Magic Cube](http://www.cs.uvm.edu/~rsnapp/teaching/cs32/lectures/rubik.pdf)

$\cdots$

Comment: Just to add, I posted links to several papers and/or texts in this thread
https://www.speedsolving.com/forum/threads/any-books-about-puzzle-theory.25458/.